# Call function from within jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm modifying the lovely [jquery.carousel.js](http://www.richardscarrott.co.uk/posts/view/jquery-carousel-plugin) plugin to have an autochange feature. I want to use `setInterval()` to call a function, but I can't get it to play nice.

Here is the code I have at the moment:

```
autoSwitch: function()
{
    if(runAuto)
    {
        $('.next').click();
    }
},
init: function(el, options) {
    if(this.options.auto)
    {
        setInterval("this.('autoSwitch')", this.options.autoTime);
    }
}
```

This is just a snippet and there is other stuff, but I've left the important bits in. 
The line I'm having trouble with is `setInterval("this.('autoSwitch')", this.options.autoTime);`. Whatever I try in the first argument of `setInterval`, it just doesn't work. So. Can you awesome people help me out as to how I call `autoSwitch()` from the `setInterval()` function please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`jQuery.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/):

```
init: function(el, options) {
    if(this.options.auto)
    {
        // Give `setInterval` a function to call
        setInterval(jQuery.proxy(this.autoSwitch, this)), this.options.autoTime);
    }
}
```

`jQuery.proxy` ensures that the function gets called with the correct *context* (`this` value). More about this general concept here: [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)

That's jQuery-specific. If you want a more general solution, you can use a closure:

```
init: function(el, options) {
    var context = this;    // Remember what `this` is in a variable
    if(this.options.auto)
    {
        // Give `setInterval` a function to call
        setInterval(function() {
            // The function is a closure that has access to
            // `context`, and so we can call it
            context.autoSwitch();
        }, this.options.autoTime);
    }
}
```

That uses a *closure* to bind the context (see: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)), which is the usual way to do this. `jQuery.proxy` just does a closure behind the scenes in a well-controlled environment so you know it's not closing over more data than you want it to.

Comment: Thank you! Just what I was looking for. The general solution is great too, but not necessary for what I'm doing though :-) Thanks again.